# Pandas .loc[].index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the most efficient way (using the least amount of lines possible) to locate and drop multiple strings in a specified column?

*Information regarding the .tsv dataset that may help*:

**'tconst'** = movie ID

**'region'** = region in which the movie was released in

**'language'** = language of movie

Here is what I have right now:

```
origin.drop(origin.columns[[1,2,5,6,7]], axis=1, inplace=True)
origin.columns = ['tconst','region','language']
origin.drop(origin.loc[origin['region']!=('US')].index, inplace=True)
```

I am trying to drop all rows under the **'region'** column that contain a string value abbreviation of countries that do not speak English. For example, drop all rows under region that are not equal to **'US','UK','AUS'**,etc. I have tried the & and or operands within the parenthesis and they tend to select and drop only one of the string values that I place inside.

**ADDITIONAL QUESTION:**

The **'language'** column contains numerous amounts of null values (I don't really care about that), however there are some rows that contain **'en'** for English. *IF* the '**region'** happens to be a non-English speaking country *BUT* the language is in English, how do I prevent those rows from being removed as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your question correctly and you want to drop the entire row if your specified conditions holds, you can write them as masks like

```
cond1 = origin['region'].isin(['US', 'UK', 'AUS'])
cond2 = origin['language'] == 'en'
```

Combining them (you want at least one of the conditions to be true in order to keep a row) with `|` you get

```
result = origin[cond1 | cond2]
```

Of course, this can also be written in a single line if you care to do so:

```
result = origin[(origin['region'].isin(['US', 'UK', 'AUS'])) | (origin['language'] == 'en')]
```

Comment: This works. Very much appreciated. Dropped the DT from 2mil+ entries to barely over 100K haha